# Count number of subsets of 3 elements either disjoint or whose intersection is a singleton

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Suppose we have a set of $n$ elements. We want to know the maximum number of subsets of $3$ elements we can find of this set such that no two subsets have an intersection with $2$ or more elements.

The question arises from trying to count the number of subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ in a group with $n$ elements of order $2$ such that the product of any two such elements has also order $2$.

Comment: Actually you title is unclear.  There are eight subsets and you want the ones that are disjoint.  Disjoint from what? Or whose intersection is a singleton.  Intersection with what?  Do you men how many *pairs* of subsets?  Or how many sets of subsets?

Comment: Subsets of what?

Comment: ... oh.... do you mean the *subsets* have three elements?  Or the super set has three elements.

Comment: @bof yeah that is right, sorry for the confusion

Comment: I interpretted it very differently than bof.  I assume the OP meant you have a set $U$ with $3$ elements, and he wants to know how many *pairs* of subsets $A \subset U$ and $B \subset U$ with $|A\cap B| = 1$ or $2$.

Comment: Wow... that wasn't at *ALL* what I thought the question was asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum possible size of a family of $3$-element subsets of an $n$-element set, no two of which have more than one element in common, is
$$\left\lfloor\frac n3\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}2\right\rfloor\right\rfloor-\varepsilon$$
where $\varepsilon=1$ if $n\equiv5\pmod6$ and $\varepsilon=0$ otherwise. This is [OEIS sequence A001839](http://oeis.org/A001839).

**References.**

T. P. Kirkman, On a problem in combinations, Cambridge and Dublin Math. J. 2 (1947), 191–204.

J. Schönheim, On maximal systems of $k$-tuples, Studia Sci. Math. Hungar. 1 (1946), 363–368.

Richard K. Guy, A problem of Zarankiewicz, in: Theory of Graphs (Proc. Colloq., Tihany 1966; P. Erdős and G. Katona, eds.), Academic Press, New York, 1968, pp. 119—150.

[Joel Spencer, Maximal consistent families of triples, J. Combin. Theory 5 (1968), 1–8.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021980068800237/pdf?md5=86b24464ed21b058b7471285f21f6d50&pid=1-s2.0-S0021980068800237-main.pdf)

J. C. Swift, Quasi Steiner systems, Atti Accad. Naz. Lincei Rend. Cl. Sci. Fis. Mat. Natur. 44 (1968), 563–569.