# Partition Adjacency Matrix of Graph into Non-Overlapping Triangles

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, binomial-coefficients, set-partition

Take an undirected, complete graph with $n$ nodes. This can be represented by an adjacency matrix of size $n^2$ with $\frac{1}{2} (n^2-n)$ independent links.

A potential triangle consists of a set of links between $3$ nodes. Labelling the nodes by the alphabet, an example of a triangle is the set $\{ab, bc, ac\}$.

I define *overlapping* as two triangles which share a common link. For example, the triangles $\{ab, bc, ac\}$ and $\{bc, cd, bd\}$ overlap. *Non-overlapping* triangles share no common link.

There are $\binom{n}{3}$ possible triangles in total, if we allow for overlap. **Q1:** What is the largest subset, if we *do not* allow for overlap? Note that $\frac{1}{6}(n^2-n)$ gives an integer for $2$ out of $3$ $n$'s.

The following *gif* shows an adjacency matrix for $n=15$ where groups of $3$ nodes are highlighted according to some algorithm. (In some browsers, you need to *refresh* to see the animation.)

[image: Adjacency Matrix]

As can be seen, the algorithm does not manage to include all links in the set of all non-overlapping triangles. Furthermore, it does not work well for $n\neq15$. **Q2:** Find an algorithm which identifies a largest list of non-overlapping triangles for arbitrary $n$.

The following *Mathematica* code may help you along:

```
myPartitionAlgorithm[n_]:=Join[Table[{1+Mod[i-1,n], 1+Mod[i,n],1+Mod[i+2,n]},{i,1,n}],Table[{1+Mod[i-1,n], 1+Mod[i+3,n],1+Mod[i+n-6,n]},{i,1,n}]]
myPartitionedGrid[n_,partition_,t_]:=Grid[Table[If[i==j,"X",StringJoin[{Alphabet[][[i]],Alphabet[][[j]]}]],{i,1,n},{j,1,n}],Frame->All,Background->{None,None,Join[Table[{i,i}->Gray,{i,1,n}],Flatten[Table[{myColor=RGBColor[i/Length[partition],N[1/2+1/2 Sin[5 i]],N[1/2+1/2 Sin[i]]];partition[[i,{1,2}]]->myColor,partition[[i,{2,3}]]->myColor,partition[[i,{1,3}]]->myColor},{i,1,t}]]]}]
Manipulate[myPartition=Map[Sort,myPartitionAlgorithm[n]];myPartitionedGrid[n,myPartition,t],{{n,15,"Number of nodes"},3,26,1},{{t,2n,"Highlighted triangles"},0,2n,1}]
```

Comment: This is the $k=3$ case of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161159/maximum-size-of-intersecting-set-families , so I suspect that Lucia's answer there provides at least some help.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Impressive how you saw that connection. It is, indeed, the same question. At the very least, it helps me use the correct nomenclature when describing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to the problem in [combinatorial design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design) of finding a largest family $F$ of $3$-element subsets of an $n$-element set $S$ such that any two sets of $F$ share at most one element. In the graph-theoretic formulation, $S$ is the vertex set of the complete graph of order $n$, and $F$ is a collection of triangles such that no two share an edge.

**Q1:** The question of the maximum size of $F$ is asked and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2598915/527345).

**Q2:** The proof of the above result is constructive, providing an explicit  construction of a largest $F$ for every $n$. The most important consideration is the remainder of $n\bmod 6$.

**Case 1:** $n\equiv1,3\pmod6$. Exactly in these two cases it is possible to include every pair of vertices in some set of $F$, i.e., every edge of the graph in some triangle. This construction is known as a [Steiner triple system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_triple_system), abbreviated STS$(n)$, and popular constructions are the Bose construction for $n\equiv3\pmod6$ and the Skolem construction for $n\equiv1\pmod6$. These can be found in many places, e.g., the [original](https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1469-1809.1939.tb02219.x) [papers](http://dx.doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-10551), a [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=jfF-rncVXNwC) on combinatorial design, or [elsewhere](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m6406/sts.pdf). The question of algorithmic implementation has been asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/72084), including [one answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/72089) that uses an existing implementation in [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/).

**Case 2:** $n\equiv0,2,4,5\pmod6$. An STS$(n)$ does not exist, and [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(68)80023-7) constructs the largest $F$ for these cases:

**Case 2a:** $n\equiv0,2\pmod6$. The maximum $F$ can be constructed by removing an element (vertex) from $S$ in the respective constructions for $n\equiv1,3\pmod6$.

**Case 2b:** $n\equiv4,5\pmod6$. The paper reduces the case of $n\equiv5\pmod6$ to that of $n\equiv4\pmod6$ and then constructs the maximum $F$ for the latter.

If you are interested in further exploration, this equivalent formulation as a problem in combinatorial design and survey of some results should help you find more resources on the topic.

Comment: Your well-documented answer is precisely what StackExchange is about: thank you. Would you be able to expand a bit on *case 2b*? I have read Joel Spencer's article and I understand the other cases, but *2b* is quite technical...

Comment: @LBogaardt Constructions of all of these cases are presented well in [_Design Theory, Second Edition_](https://books.google.com/books?id=OoRFisqn-aIC) by Charles C. Lindner and Christopher A. Rodger. In particular, in section $4.2$ on maximum packings, they easily obtain the $n\equiv4,5\pmod6$ cases from a PBD of order $6n+5$ with one block of size $5$ and the remaining blocks of size $3$, known as the $6n+5$ construction, which can also be [found](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-23223-7_82.pdf) [elsewhere](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m6406/sts.pdf).