# Set system where any subset is not contained in the union of any two others

Tags: combinatorics

I would like to find a set system $\mathcal{F}$ over $n$ elements such that $\forall A, B, C \in \mathcal{F}$, $A \nsubseteq B \cup C$. This is trivial to achieve without any restriction on the size of $\mathcal{F}$: just take the $n$ singletons. However, I would be interested in solutions that achieve this with the size of $\mathcal{F}$ being exponential or at the very least quadratic in $n$ (and ideally not just asymptotically, but also for small values of $n$).

Does anyone know of any construction achieving this or, alternatively, any impossibility results?
I tried looking for set systems with small pairwise intersections, i.e. if sets are of size at least $k$, enforce that all intersections are of size less than $k/2$. An upperbound for this I thought could have a flavour similar to the Ray-Choudhuri-Wilson theorem, but this has no constraint on the relative size between the sets and their intersection and I could not manage to extend in any meaningful way. Moreover, a paper by Beideman and Blocki on "Set Families with Low Pairwise Intersection" gives a construction that could work but that needs too high values or $n$ ($n>2000$) even to achieve the quadratic relationship between $n$ and the size of $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: P. Erdős, P. Frankl, and Z. Füredi, Families of finite sets in which no set is covered by the union of $r$ others, *Israel J. Math.* 51 (1985), 79–89 [(pdf)](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~z-furedi/PUBS/furedi_frankl_erdos_1985_r-cover.pdf)

Comment: P. Erdős, P. Frankl, and Z. Füredi, Families of finite sets in which no set is covered by the union of two others, *J. Combin. Theory Ser. A* 33 (1982), 158–166 [(pdf)](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~z-furedi/PUBS/furedi_erdos_frankl_2cover_free.pdf)

Comment: If you're satisfied with $|\mathcal F|$ being only quadratic in $n$, what's wrong with Steiner triple systems? Don't they give you $|\mathcal F|=\frac{n^2}6-O(n)$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, @bof. I will definitely have a close look at those papers (I am also interested in the generic case considering union of r sets), although it's not obvious to me whether their proofs are constructive yet...
Steiner triples should indeed give me something interesting, thanks for that tip! Do you know by any chance any work/review somewhat clearly stating which Steiner systems we can construct? From what I understand, we know a fair bit about which ones exists, but it was not clear which ones we can construct...

Comment: Even for values of $n$ where a Steiner triple system doesn't exist, the maximum size of a family of triples intersecting pairwise in at most one point is known exactly; see the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2598915/count-number-of-subsets-of-3-elements-either-disjoint-or-whose-intersection-is-a).

Comment: Thanks so much!